# Unexpected behaviour of copy.deepcopy

Tags: python, list, copy

In the following code snipped deepcopy does not work as I expected:

```
import copy

wp = [[1], [2], [3]]
wp_temp = list()
wp_temp.append(wp[1])
wp_temp.append(wp[0])
wp_temp.append(wp[0])

wp = copy.deepcopy(wp_temp)
print(wp)
>>>[[2], [1], [1]]
wp[1].append(10)
print(wp)
>>>[[2], [1, 10], [1, 10]]
```

I would have expected the outcome `[[2], [1, 10], [1]]`. What am I doing wrong? It seems my understanding is not correct. What would be the simplest code to get the expected behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) states (emphasis mine):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
> compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
> class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
> the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
> original.
>
> Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist
> with shallow copy operations:
>
> Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly, contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop.
>
> Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, such as data which is intended to be shared between copies.
>
> The deepcopy() function avoids these problems by:
>
> **keeping a memo dictionary of objects already copied during the current copying pass**; and
>
> letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied.

by having two references of the same list in your code:

ie

```
wp_temp.append(wp[0])
wp_temp.append(wp[0]) # same reference
```

`deepcopy` **will take note that there is same reference through its `memo` store** and actually **create only one copy** and use a reference to that copy for second reference.

This answers your question.

The solution is to copy the list in the first place ie:

```
wp_temp.append(wp[0])
wp_temp.append(wp[0][:]) # shallow copy, not same reference
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, because `wp_temp[1]` and `wp_temp[2]` are just two references to the same list `[1]`.
When you did deepcopy, `wp` has the same structure as `wp_temp`: a list of three elements, two of them reference the same list `[1]`.

So when you append 10 to it, actuelly you added the element `10` to the list which is references by two elements of your list `wp`.

If you want to get the expected result you have to do copies of `wp[0]`:

```
import copy

wp = [[1], [2], [3]]
wp_temp = list()
wp_temp.append(wp[1])
wp_temp.append(copy.copy(wp[0]))   # do a copy here
wp_temp.append(copy.copy(wp[0]))   # do a copy here

wp = copy.deepcopy(wp_temp)
print(wp)
>>>[[2], [1], [1]]
wp[1].append(10)
print(wp)
>>>[[2], [1, 10], [1, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your setup, the 2nd and 3rd elements of the list point to the same reference when you append to wp_temp

Here's one way to get your output:

```py
from copy import copy

wp = [[1], [2], [3]]
wp_temp = list()
wp_temp.append(list(wp[1]))
wp_temp.append(list(wp[0]))
wp_temp.append(list(wp[0]))

wp = copy(wp_temp)
wp[1].append(10)
print(wp)
## -- End pasted text --
[[2], [1, 10], [1]]
```

Comment: Youo don't need to do deepcopy as `wp[0]` is a simple list. a simple `copy` is enough

Answer (score 1):

You are storing references in your list. This means, you append the same reference with `wp_temp.append(wp[0])` of your list twice.

You can fix this by creating a new list of the same item:

```
wp = [[1], [2], [3]]
wp_temp = list()
wp_temp.append(list(wp[1]))
wp_temp.append(list(wp[0]))
wp_temp.append(list(wp[0]))

wp = copy.deepcopy(wp_temp)
wp[1].append(10)
# content is: [[2], [1, 10], [1]]
```